# SQL Query to select the Max sales for each customer and the date

Tags: sql, max

[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltgKT.png)

SQL Query to find the Customer ID, their Max Purch_amt and Date when the Max Purch happened.
Can anyone please help? Struggling a bit here.
Data structure attached in the Link.

Comment: mysql, or sql-server or postgres or Oracle?

Comment: Please do  not post pictures of text. Post the text and show what you have attempted.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
select 
ord_no, 
purch_amt,
ord_date
from 
(
select 
*,
rank() over (partition by customerid order by purch_amt desc) as r
from orders
)O
where r=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! I am using a subquery to SELECT the maximum purchase amount per customer and then I added their respective date.

```
WITH A AS (SELECT customer_id, MAX(Purch_amt) FROM orders)
SELECT a.*, o.ord_date
FROM A
JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).